# Java Number While Loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm in a university and I don't understand how to fix this problem. I'm trying to make a program where a user types in all the numbers s/he wants, and enter -1 when s/he is done. "Expected" results are as directed by my professor:

Write a program that will allow the user to enter any number of positive integers.
The user will enter a -1 when they are done entering numbers
(do not include the -1 as a number).
The program must print out, when the user is done entering numbers, the following:
Which number had the longest run of identical values, and how long the run was
The minimum number entered
The maximum number entered
For example, if the user enters these numbers:

- 5
- 9
- 5
- 7
- 5
- 7
- -1

Then the program would print out:

```
Longest run: 5 entered 3 times
Minimum number: 2
Maximum number: 9
```

If there are multiple runs of equal length, print out the first such run encountered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExSixNumber {

  public static void main(String args []) {
    int mostUsedNumber = 0;
    int mostUsedCount = 0;

    System.out.println("I will track all your numbers!");
    System.out.println("Enter any digits between 1 and 9.");
    System.out.println("Enter '-1' when done:");

    Scanner scn = new Scanner (System.in);

    while(scn.hasNext()) {
        String userInput = scn.next();
        while (scn.equals (userInput)) {
            mostUsedNumber++;
            mostUsedCount++;
        }
        if(userInput.equals("-1")) {
            System.out.println("Your tracked data:");
            System.out.println("Longest run: " + mostUsedNumber + " entered " + mostUsedCount + " .");

            break;
        }            
    }
  }
}
```

This is as far as I had gotten. It doesn't like to track my userInput, could someone point me in the right direction on improving the program? I'm new and not asking for a direct answer, but "dummy" terms would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: What do you think the inner while loop does?

Comment: @Julio, I was thinking it'd track if the scanner matched the userInput (let's assume they insert 5). So if there were four fives in the entries, it's say "You used 5 a total of 4 times."

Comment: I used the idex++; method to try seeing if it's skipped or not.

Comment: The problem is that `mostUsedNumber` and `mostUsedCount` can get overwritten by the next number, so you could write 5 5 5 5 4 and get "You used 4 a total of 1 times." But that's another case compared to what is happening, the ++ increments +1 on what was already in the variable. Each iteration in your current code would end up incrementing it. Check aliteralmind's answer too. Hint: mostUsedNumber would not need ++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help :)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class one {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int mostUsedNumber = 0;
    int mostUsedCount = 0;

    int maxNo=-1;
    int minNo=-1;

    List numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    List mostOccuranceList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("I will track all your numbers!");
    System.out.println("Enter any digits between 1 and 9.");
    System.out.println("Enter '-1' when done:");

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (scn.hasNext()) {

        String userInput = scn.next().trim();

        int user_input = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

        if(maxNo==-1 && minNo ==-1){
            maxNo=minNo=user_input;
        }

        if (user_input > 0 && user_input < 10) {

            // returns the number of occurrences
            int occurrences = Collections.frequency(numberList,user_input);

            if (occurrences == mostUsedCount) {
                mostOccuranceList.add(user_input);
            } else if (occurrences > mostUsedCount) {
                mostUsedCount = occurrences;
                // emptying the most occurrence list since current input is the most frequent number
                mostOccuranceList.removeAll(mostOccuranceList);
                mostOccuranceList.add(user_input);
            }
            if(user_input>maxNo)
            {
                maxNo=user_input;
            }

            if(user_input<minNo){
                minNo=user_input;
            }
            numberList.add(user_input);

        }

        mostUsedNumber+=1;
        mostUsedNumber=Integer.parseInt(mostOccuranceList.get(0).toString());
        if (userInput.equals("-1")) {
            System.out.println("Your tracked data:");
            System.out.println("Longest run: " + mostOccuranceList + " entered " + mostUsedCount + " .");
            System.out.println("Maximum Number :- "+maxNo);
            System.out.println("Minimum Number :- "+minNo);
            break;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, this was a little hard to read at first, but it's self explanatory. :) I figured an array was to go, but I didn't know how to add to it. But question, what exactly is maxNo and minNo for? and parseInt? Other than that I understand how the  script runs.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond. The assignment was pushed due to severe weather and my professor had given us a lab due, so this assignment was pushed back a bit.

Comment: maxNo :- To store the number with largest value, 
minNo   :- To store the number with smallest value, 
parseInt :- Since the input is received as String it need to be converted to Int.